# Trying to get a ILI9341 TFT to work with UTFT library

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

I'm currently trying to fill out the constructor but I'm not sure what's what...
The constructor of the UTFT library goes as follows:

```
UTFT(Model, SDA, SCL, CS, RST[, RS]);
```

Where the last bit is optional.

SDA meaning Serial Data, SCL serial clock, CS chip select, RST reset and RS register select.

[image]

This is the screen I'm trying to connect. As far as I understand:

SDI (MOSI) goes to SDA

SCK goes to SCL

CS  goes to CS

RST goes to Reset?

RS goes to D/C?

But it doesn't work. What am I missing...

Here's my full code:

```
#include <UTFT.h>

//Digital Pins:
//53 = MOSI 
//52 = SCK, 
//10 = CS 
//6 = RS 
//7 = D/C
UTFT myGLCD(ILI9341_S5P,53,52,10,6,7);  

void setup() {
    myGLCD.InitLCD(PORTRAIT);
    myGLCD.clrScr();

}

void loop() {
    myGLCD.fillScr(0,0,255);

}
```

I did get the screen to work with the Adafruit_GFX library. I used 1k resistors between all of the data lines, including reset. When using the screen with the GFX library I connected reset to 3,3v.

Comment: SDA/SCL is I2C (Wire). MISO/MOSI/CLK/CS is SPI

Comment: from where do you have the UTFT library? I don't see one in Library Manager

Comment: @Juraj found it on rinky-dink electronics: http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/library.php?id=51

Comment: the library is not for SPI connected display

Comment: `it doesn't work` does not describe the observed results.

Comment: @Juraj , thank you for clearing that up. I will look out for a different library then. Can you tell me how you found out that it's not for SPI displays, apart from looking at SDA/SCL being for I2C? I'm still new to arduino.

Comment: the library you linked has documentation in the downloaded zip. and of course there is the source code not using SPI

Comment: and reset of a device should be connected to a gpio pin, to be able to reset the device from sketch